# How to include JOIN in IF statement in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
   if(B1=""," ",
     IF(C1=" ","NONE", 
       IF(AND('FORM'!$N:$U=B1,'FORM'!$N:$U=C1),'FORM'!$Z:$Z,
         "OK"
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

For the most part it seems to be working but the second part of the statement "IF(AND" I need to join B1 and C1 and search for that joined string in FORM! N:U.

How do I add the JOIN operator in here?

[Demo file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h7xpSBva_pYDgxfe7BmAdl36i7ZebfBjNK4HcKRCRnQ/edit)

Comment: Can you share an example because there a few portions of your formula that don't make sense

Comment: So I've managed to get the formula working in this format:       =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER('1ON1FORM'!$AB:$AB,('1ON1FORM'!$BR:$BR=B91)*('1ON1FORM'!$BS:$BS=C91)),1,1),"AVAILABLE")

Comment: Aweome! Sorry i didnt get back to you! I wasnt feeling well on Sunday :(

Comment: How could I extend this so that the search range is B:G for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a different solution to my challenge.

See question/answer here:  [Google Sheet Query stopped working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913635/google-sheet-query-stopped-working-as-expected)

Thanks for all the help offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&` operator instead - by doing `B1&C1` -

also there are a few other corrections I would suggest about your formula because some of doesn't make sense - I am happy to do that if you can share some sample data because it is impossible to guess what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Aurielle...Here is a link to an example sheet...I've pulled it down to the bare bones for the purpose of this particular formula. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h7xpSBva_pYDgxfe7BmAdl36i7ZebfBjNK4HcKRCRnQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I was using B1 and c1 for the question but you will see what I'm trying to achieve I think.

Comment: I also need the value to be reutrned to be the first found by time/datestamp

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, you basically just switched `if` & `and` `+` and should be the sign. so -> `& if()`
I made a simple one here. I don't know how to make it more simple, but maybe with some `VLOOCKUP`?

Just change `HVIS => IF` (mine is danish)

[Preview on my ark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC0HV.png)

codes:

```
=HVIS(B1>0;A1;) & HVIS(B2>0;A2;) & HVIS(B3>0;"-A3";) 
  & HVIS(B4>0;A4;) & HVIS(B5>0;A5;) & HVIS(B6>0;A6;) 
  & HVIS(B7>0;A7;) & HVIS(B8>0;A8;)


=HVIS(B11>0;A11;) & HVIS(B12>0;("-" & A12);) 
 & HVIS(B13>0;("-" & A13);) & HVIS(B14>0;("-" & A14);) 
 & HVIS(B15>0;("-" & A15);) & HVIS(B16>0;("-" & A16);) 
 & HVIS(B17>0;("-" & A17);) & HVIS(B18>0;("-" & A18);)
```