# Google Sheet Query stopped working as expected

Tags: google-sheets

I had the formula below working beautifully a day ago.... where it would give me the first two results found and they would be in one cell under the other. I had to reset the form response destination but recreated it virtually as it was. After that change last night they started showing with a different format, where there were multiple names showing in 1 cell instead of 1 name in the first cell/row, then the second in the next cell/row.

`"=IFERROR(QUERY('1ON1FORM'!$O$3:$AX, "select AX where O contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and O contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or P contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and P contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or Q contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and Q contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or R contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and R contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or S contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and S contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or T contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and T contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or U contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and U contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or V contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and V contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or W contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and W contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or X contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and X contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or Y contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and Y contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or Z contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and Z contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or AA contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and AA contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or AB contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and AB contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&"""  or AC contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and AC contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or AD contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and AD contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or AE contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and AE contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&""" or AF contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and AF contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&"""  or AG contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and AG contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&"""  or AH contains date """&text(B17,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and AH contains timeofday """&text(C17,"HH:mm:ss")&"""limit 2"),"")"`

I need the formula to show the first two only. What could have changed the way this is displaying?

Note....I know this is an extremely long formula and would appreciate any suggestion on how to reduce it or somehow include it in a script but I gave up after I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All

Found the solution here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/6XNpHLGOOpw

All working beautifully now.

The magic of 0 :)

Happy Days!